# TypeScript - 'this' defaults to 'any'

Tags: typescript

Can some one please explain why i do not get intellisense in 'setItem' function for 'this' variable. My understanding it should be scoped to '_storageAdapter' property?

```
class TestClass {
private testOne = () => {
}

_storageAdapter: {
    toType: (obj: any) => string,
    getItem: (key: string) => void,
    setItem: (key: string, value: string) => void,
}
= {
    toType: (obj: any) => {
        return "hello";
    },
    getItem: (key: string) => {
        this.testOne() // this is class scoped;
    },
    setItem: function (key: string, value: any) {
        this.toType(value); // this should be property scoped? but no intellisense? its just set to 'any'
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Regular js functions don't save the scope of `this`, for example:

```
class A {
    obj = {
        withoutScope: function() {
            console.log(this);
        },

        withScope: () => {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Compiles into:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
        var _this = this;
        this.obj = {
            withoutScope: function () {
                console.log(this);
            },
            withScope: function () {
                console.log(_this);
            }
        };
    }
    return A;
}());
```

Notice the difference between the two `console.log`: the `withoutScope` has `this` while `withScope` has `_this` (which is defined above as `var _this = this`).
This is how the typescript compiler translates the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), but if you compile it with `ES6` target then it will keep it as an arrow function without using the `_this = this` trick, but the result will be the same.

If you call those methods you get:

```
let a = new A();
a.obj.withoutScope(); // Object {}
a.obj.withScope(); // A { obj: Object }
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%09obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09%09withoutScope%3A%20function()%20%7B%0A%09%09%09console.log(this)%3B%0A%09%09%7D%2C%0A%09%09%0A%09%09withScope%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09%09console.log(this)%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0Aa.obj.withoutScope()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Object%20%7B%7D%0Aa.obj.withScope()%3B%20%2F%2F%20A%20%7B%20obj%3A%20Object%20%7D))

The same happens in your example, the first two functions are arrow functions which keep the right scope of `this`, but the third doesn't.
You can either use an arrow function there as well or you can use the [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

```
setItem: function (key: string, value: any) {
    this.toType(value); // this should be property scoped? but no intellisense? its just set to 'any'
}.bind(this)
```

But it will probably only help you at runtime, as I'm not sure that your intellisense will get that.

Comment: Thank you. I guess my gripe with this is that then there is no way for error check on build or compile time. You can type this.ANYTHING in setItem and it will only brake on runtime. Also, regardless using fat arrow or regular functions you cant call internal function within _storageAdapter only outside the _storageAdapter property. Bummer

Comment: You can use an arrow function like with the other two, but why don't you just have those functions as class methods and you hold them in that object?

Comment: Yes. I can extract that to an interface optionally and a class. I was just trying to see how far i can push TS before it will fail to give me strongly typed objects and intellisense.

Comment: From my experience, if you design things right then typescript will go as far as you need it to. If you'll explain what you're trying to do I (or someone else) might help you get to a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified sample:

```
class TestClass {
    private testOne = () => {
    }

    _storageAdapter: {
        getItem: (key: string) => void,
        setItem: (key: string, value: string) => void,
    }
    = {
        getItem: (key: string) => {
            this.testOne() // this is class scoped;
        },
        setItem: function (key: string, value: any) {
            this.somethingThatDoesNotExist(); // this should be property scoped? but no intellisense? its just set to 'any'
        }
    }
}
```

The reason is that `function` does not capture `this` and it will really depend on the user of the function how they call it.

An arrow function captures `this` so typescript has stronger guarantee.

## More

- Arrow function : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Some flags that will prevent you getting caught off guard: `noImplicitAny` https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/options/noImplicitAny.html